# Description of 30 Dajjals

Tags: dajjal

I know that the main Dajjal will have one eye, Kufr written on his forehead and other things. But I have read that there will be thirty dajjal before him. My question is that is there any hadith of the description of these thirty dajjals.

Comment: Some scholars rejected the idea that even one of them exists, now you come and say they might be 30, what's your evidence for that?

Answer (score 2):

There be no description of their features or any details except they are all liars who claim to be prophet, although there is no prophet after Mohammed (SAW)

> The Last Hour would not come until there would arise about thirty
>   impostors, liars, and each one of them would claim that he is a
>   messenger of Allah.
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/108
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/68